# messages.error() not formatting correctly, but .success() does

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Having an issue with `messages.error()` not showing up on the html template properly.

I have a `Participant` models where Users register their participants in a research project. When they complete the registration form, the custom `form_valid()` method within the `CreateView` sends off to another function which assess the new patient's eligibility - if eligible the form is saved to the model and a `messages.success()` is shown. If they are not eligible, the form is not saved and a `messages.error()` should be shown.

Currently, all of the eligibility check functionality works perfectly and if eligible the success message is shown. However, when not eligible the error message does not show properly. The text is shown on the redirect page, however it is not formatted as an error message should be in the red box.

views.py

```
class ParticipantRegisterView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Participant
    form_class = ParticipantRegisterForm
    template_name = 'participants/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:dashboard')

    def participant_eligible(self, temp):
        if not temp.is_eligible:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.provider = self.request.user
        temp = form.save(commit=False)
        if self.participant_eligible(temp):
            messages.success(self.request, 'Participant registered')
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            messages.error(self.request, 'Participant ineligible')
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('accounts:dashboard'))
```

relevant portion of base.html that the template for 'accounts:dashboard' extends

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  ...
  <main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        {% if messages %}
          {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
              {{ message }}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</html>
```

Is there perhaps something that happens within the `redirect()` function that removes the tag for the message? The text still shows up, but not the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

You are using bootstrap, which has styles for `alert-success`, but not for `alert-error` which is what your HTML will generate for an error message (note that Django doesn't do any styling for you).

If you want to style `alert-error` then you need to do this yourself. Bootstrap does have an `alert-danger` class, which is probably similar to what you want, in which case you need to add CSS to style `alert-error` similarly to `alert-danger` e.g.,:

```
.alert-error {
    color: #721c24;
    background-color: #f8d7da;
    border-color: #f5c6cb;
}
```

Also note that `messages.tags` is actually a space-separated list of tags, so you can end up with classes that are not prefixed with `alert-`.